# set the username who update my table or column?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have table and some users are allowed to update a specific column in it i made a column so the user who update the column but this is useless  since that column update by the person it self so is their away to update this column automatically by the system ?? 
I found away by suing trigger but i am not allowed to use triggers  so any function or any simple way to do it ?

thanks

Comment: Step 1. Stop allowing users to update your data directly and put an UI or API in front of your table.

Comment: My wild guess. Try using current_user. Its a session variable that tells the the logged in user. Like "show user" on prompt and whoami on Unix.